# How do I turn off sports alerts on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios

I don't follow sports and am getting too many alerts when I casually started showing an interest.

I'd like to turn them off, but I don't see where in the TV app to disable them.  I tried in settings, but while settings\TV does have a section for ESPN and other channels, when I disable it in settings, it says I need to do it in the app.

I can't find where to do it in the app, and now I'm in a vicious cycle where I feel like I'm in the [33rd inning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_professional_baseball_game) of a baseball game.  I need a break.

Comment: What app do the alerts come from?